# I can't call service from controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call service from my controller

```
leadService.loadPage.query({pageNumber: pageNumber}, success, error);
```

*Service definition*

```
define([], function() {
    return ['$resource', function ($resource) {

        return {
            loadPage: loadPage
        };


        function loadPage() {
            return $resource('http://localhost/api/loadPage/:pageNumber', null, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {
                        pageNumber: '1'
                    },
                    isArray: true
                }
            });
        }
    }]
})
```

It shows error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. It probably can't fire `query` statement.
I'm using RequireJS with AngularJS.

Comment: Maybe because you try to define `loadPage` *after* your return?

Comment: Additionally: loadPage is a method instead of an object. You'll get a `function has no method query`.

Comment: yes but the call should be `leadService.loadPage().query({pageNumber: pageNumber}, success, error);` instead of `leadService.loadPage.query({pageNumber: pageNumber}, success, error);`

Comment: @LuisMasuelli yeah noticed that after I commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here. The first one was spotted by @MannyD. You must fix the function definition like this (i.e. declaring the function before the return statement which references it):

```
define([], function() {
    return ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        function loadPage() {
            return $resource('http://localhost/api/loadPage/:pageNumber', null, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {
                        pageNumber: '1'
                    },
                    isArray: true
                }
            });
        }

        return {
            loadPage: loadPage
        };
    }]
})
```

The second problem is the one I spotted: a call like `leadService.loadPage.query({pageNumber: pageNumber}, success, error);` will trigger an error because `loadPage` is a function and not a `$reource`. You must **either** add the parens in the definition **OR** add the parent in the call. This means:

```
define([], function() {
    return ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        function loadPage() {
            return $resource('http://localhost/api/loadPage/:pageNumber', null, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {
                        pageNumber: '1'
                    },
                    isArray: true
                }
            });
        }

        return {
            loadPage: loadPage()
        };
    }]
});

//...

leadService.loadPage.query({pageNumber: pageNumber}, success, error);
```

**OR**

```
define([], function() {
    return ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        function loadPage() {
            return $resource('http://localhost/api/loadPage/:pageNumber', null, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    params: {
                        pageNumber: '1'
                    },
                    isArray: true
                }
            });
        }

        return {
            loadPage: loadPage
        };
    }]
});

//...

leadService.loadPage().query({pageNumber: pageNumber}, success, error);
```

Comment: Good job @Luis, I was misled, because I'm using the same concept with `$http`. So thanks for useful solution!